# Mushrooms for Mishloach Manos

Tags: halacha, purim, mishloach-manot, mushrooms

Can one give Mushrooms for Mishloach Manos? Since you have to give real food and with mushrooms:

1 - You can't make an Erev Tnachmin with it.

2 - You buy it with money of Ma'aser Sheini.

3 - You make a Bracha Shehakol on it.

So it must be not a real kind of food.

Comment: You make Shehakol on pastrami and I doubt any non vegetarian would be disappointed to find a pound of it in their Mishloach Manos

Comment: @JoshK, depends on whether it's MealMart or Mr. Broadway. One is meh, the other is takeh gevaldig

Comment: Providing a source for your assertion that mushrooms aren't a real food would help. How did you come to such a conclusion?

Comment: Meshalach Manos need to be ready to eat. Nearly all mushrooms need to be cooked before being eaten so unless you are using the very few examples of gourmet mushrooms that don't need to be cooked and aren't commonly found in stores you might have an issue with giving someone a raw ingredient rather than a ready to consume food.